# How can I implement flow control (*execution* of if-else, for... while....) in ANTLR?

Tags: java, antlr

I am a beginner at ANTLR, I have the 2 books by it's creator and I am reading a lot of blogs/forums posts but it seems that I just don't get it right now.

All I can find is grammar code for this, and tree grammar code for this, but I just can't understand how exactly a control flow is made out of this.

Because I suppose that I can't put my question clear enough for you, let me put it that way:

Can you please show me all necessary code that upon passing to the parser

```
for (i=0; i!=3; i=i+1) {
   if (i==2) print i;
   else print "not 2";
}
```

Will output:

```
not 2  
not 2  
2
```

Preferably in Java.

Edit: I found a small project hosted at code.google.com that uses ANTLR, and based on it I understood how silly is my question ! :)

Comment: What you've asked for is a **lot** more than just parsing. You've asked for compilation and execution, as well. A parser takes source code as input and produces an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree). It does not run the code.

Comment: Greg, I meant to ask where exactly the magic if-else and for... happens, I don't know if I have to place something in the Parser, or it should be in my Visitor.

Comment: You might not need compilation and execution, but you will need at least to "interpret" your program to simulate the effects of the semantics of your program. ANTLR gets you to having a parse, and with additional effort, the AST which is a great foundation for writing such an interpreter. Interpreters written on ASTs are generally not really hard, but ANTLR simply hands you the AST and lets you implement what you want (an interpreter or compiler as you like).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a scanner/parser, Antlr only implements what we call the *front end* of a compiler. Antlr's task is to take free-form text and turn it into a data structure that's easy for programs - particularly compiler back ends - to work with.

Writing that compiler back end (or interpreter, or whatever) is still your job, I'm afraid!

Comment: I see :) I was confused because an example in the book by Terence Parr have a for cycle, which includes the variables "first" in the declaration part and "inc" at the end of the for, which I suppose represents incrementing, and I didn't find any declarations for these "first" and "inc" in the code, and they are in italic text in AntlrWorks, so I thought that they are built-in and are used for the actual for-cycle somehow.